Does Android require the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to scan for Bluetooth devices?
I don't know what location has to do with Bluetooth, but my app won't recognize any Bluetooth devices unless it is granted the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission. Even granting it the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION doesn't work.
I don't like this behavior. My app has nothing to do with location or tracking but now my users have to receive and accept a pop-up asking for permission to access precise location. I think a lot of users will say No, and then won't understand why the app won't recognize their Bluetooth device.
Am I missing something?

Try to strongly assert in the bluetooth permissions that your app never derives physical location from Bluetooth scan results like that:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
                 android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />

So without that declared if you don’t explicitly declare the location permession the system will prevent you from recognizing any bluetooth device
Try reading this part of the documentation for more infos:
https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/bt-permissions#assert-never-for-location

If your app targets Android 11 (API level 30) or lower, you need to declare the following permissions in your app's manifest file, ant the location must be turned ON for scanning.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


BLUETOOTH permission to make connection to Bluetooth device.
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to scan for Bluetooth devices.

If your app targets Android 12 (API level 31) or higher, declare the following permissions in your app's manifest file:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />


BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission to make connection to Bluetooth device.
BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission to scan for Bluetooth devices.

neverForLocation flag is necessary or else scan will not work properly.
NB: If your app targets Android 12 (API level 31) or higher and you are scanning for a BLE beacon device,
don't add flag neverForLocation and the location must be turned ON for scanning.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


Note that even if your app targets api 31 or higher, you need to declare location permission if you want it to work on old devices running Android 11 or lower.
