Missing Permission: Portability Android 13 app to Android11
I would like to share a problem I've been having.
I developed an Android Studio application aimed at communicating with my ESP32 via BLE. I developed and tested my application on a Samsung S22 (Android 13) but now on Android 11 I've some issues.
I created a service with

Two characteristics, read/notify, which allows my ESP32 to send data to my smartphone (like temperature from a sensor, for example)

Write characteristic that allows my smartphone to activate pins/ports on my ESP32.


Function Send data to ESP  :
public void sendBLEData(byte[] data) {

  mWriteCharacteristic.setValue(data);

  if (mBluetoothGatt == null || mWriteCharacteristic == null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth not ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
  }

  if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
  }

  boolean result = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mWriteCharacteristic);
  if (!result) {
    Log.e("BLE Error", "Failed to write data");
  }
}

Function use the SendBLEData :
if (!humiditeActivee) {
  mHumidite.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed)));
  mHumidite.setText("Humidification ON");
  chronoHume.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + chronoHumeStoppedTime[0]);
  chronoHume.start();
  sendBLEData("ON_H".getBytes());
  humiditeActivee = true;
}

mWriteCharacteristic is initialized in ScanActivity :
BluetoothGattCharacteristic mWriteCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristic(WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);
if (mWriteCharacteristic == null) {
  Log.e(TAG, "Write characteristic not found!");
  return; // Exit if no write characteristic found
}

The remaining issue is with sending data from the smartphone, particularly the mWriteCharacteristic, which returns null, in the SendBLEData, the  function stops at the first if and print "Bluetooth not ready",  therefore I'm not able to send data to my esp32.
Does anyone have an idea about another permission that could be blocking the application?
I would like to point out that the ESP works perfectly if I control it from a generic BLE app found on the smartphone store. thanks
My application does not work well on Android 11. After some research, I managed to adapt my application, notably because of certain permissions like
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
  obj.mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(context, false, obj.mGattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE);
}


Welcome to Stack Overflow. The two Android versions require different Bluetooth permissions. This must be taken into account by the app and implemented accordingly.

Android's Bluetooth permissions differ by version. Refer to this question for specifics: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78498048/does-android-require-the-access-fine-location-permission-to-scan-for-bluetooth-d/78500221#78500221. Enabling Location/GPS may be necessary for successful connections in Android versions below 11.

Is your problem solved now or you need additional assistance.

Hi, thanks for your anwsers, Unfortunatly it's still not working, i cheked all permissions, and the function sendBLEData still has mWriteCharacteristic Null.. the functions ReadBLEData, scan and connect still working correctly...

' "android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
"android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
"android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
"android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
"android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
"android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>'
this is the permission in my AndroidManifest.xml , @VishnuSDharan, unless I am mistaken therer is all permission for BLE ?

The issue you're facing is likely caused by attempting to write to a Bluetooth GATT characteristic (writeCharacteristic) before it has been fully discovered.
To resolve this, make sure you discover services and characteristics immediately after establishing a successful connection to the BLE device. Only then you should initialize the characteristics
Your gatt callback may be something like this.
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
    if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        gatt.discoverServices(); // this should be the first gatt operation
    } 
    // Handle other connection states here
}

@Override
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        // Initialize characteristic here
}

NB: Try to do gatt operations one by one (e.g. read only after onServicesDiscovered() is triggered, write only after onCharacteristicRead is triggered, next operation only after onCharacteristicWrite is triggered, so and so)

Hi, thanks for your answer, i changed the order and take care of this in the code , unfortunatly, it's still not working for the moment...
